# Token Reset using TimedJSONWebSignatureSerializer

Tags: python, flask

I'm implementing password reset using `itsdangerous` `TimedJSONWebSignatureSerializer` in my flask application, on sending the email address I get the following stack trace in make-header `exp = iat + self.expires_in` and finally, `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'`. What is it that I don't do right?

I have tried changing the id to an integer, but have not succeeded. Researched on decoding but that seems fine.

## This is my code:

```
from datetime import datetime
from flask import current_app
from inventory import db, login_manager
from flask_login import UserMixin
from itsdangerous import TimedJSONWebSignatureSerializer as Serializer


@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(int(user_id))


class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    fullname = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    phone = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True, nullable=False)
    image_file = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default='default.jpg')
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    items = db.relationship('Items', backref='items_admin', lazy=True)
    orderitems = db.relationship('OrderItems', backref='user_order', lazy=True)

    def get_reset_token(self, expires_sec=30000):
        s = Serializer(current_app.config['SECRET_KEY'], expires_sec)
        return s.dumps({'user_id': self.id}).decode('ascii') # This is the line that throws the said error.

    @staticmethod
    def verify_reset_token(token):
        s = Serializer(current_app.config['SECRET_KEY'])
        try:
            user_id = s.loads(token)['user_id']
        except:
            return None
        return User.query.get(user_id)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User('{self.username}', '{self.email}', '{self.image_file}')"
```

I expect a reset link be send to the given email address seamlessly.

Comment: Just curios. Can you paste the code where you are using the get_reset_token method?

Comment: def send_reset_email(user):
    token = User.get_reset_token(user)
    msg = Message('Password Reset Request',
                  sender='noreply@demo.com',
                  recipients=[user.email])
    msg.body = f'''To reset your password, visit the following link:
{url_for('users.reset_token', token=token, _external=True)}

If you did not make this request then simply ignore this email and no changes will be made.
'''
    mail.send(msg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that `expires_sec` is an integer when calling `get_reset_token` and you are overriding `expires_sec` argument.

This is because when the `expires_in` value passed to Serializer instance is a string it throws the exception as shown below.

```
from itsdangerous import TimedJSONWebSignatureSerializer as Serializer
s = Serializer('your_secret_key', expires_in="36000") # when expires_in value is a string it raises the TypeError exception.
s.dumps({'id': 'your_user_id'}).decode('ascii')
```

It raises the exception you have highlighted above

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-1f720d87ecbf> in <module>
----> 1 s.dumps({'id': '232232'}).decode('ascii')

   178         header = JSONWebSignatureSerializer.make_header(self, header_fields)
    179         iat = self.now()
--> 180         exp = iat + self.expires_in
    181         header["iat"] = iat
    182         header["exp"] = exp

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Solution: Check where you are calling `get_reset_token` and make sure you are not overriding `expires_sec` with a string value. if your doing so, use an integer value

Comment: I did check and also realized that I had left out an import i.e the User. Thank you so much.